# Error when i implement HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule and TranslateModule together

Tags: angular, import, httpclient, angular-translate

I'm trying to use HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule and TranslateModule together but something isn't well.

I have the following code :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// Services

import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
],
```

I remove TranslateModule from array imports and there works!, but when they are together do not work.
I hope that can you help me, thanks!

The error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [object Object]
Error: [object Object]
at viewWrappedDebugError (core.js:9504)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14750)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14041)
at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:10960)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3922)
at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:11157)
at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:6543)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5630)
at eval (router.js:5570)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at viewWrappedDebugError (core.js:9504)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14750)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14041)
at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:10960)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3922)
at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:11157)
at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:6543)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5630)
at eval (router.js:5570)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
at eval (zone.js:873)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
at <anonymous>
```

Comment: I guess TranslateModule comes from [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), is that correct? It looks like your code is missing some imports (not the angular imports, but in the TS imports), like HttpClient, TranslateLoader and TranslateModule. Also, how does your HttpLoaderFactory look like?

Comment: Yes, comes from ngx-translate, really i have the imports, i edited the post including all the imports that i have.  thanks!

Comment: Alright, nice. So what I see is that you are using the HttpClient service that is recommended for the current angular version. But you are currently not importing the relative HttpClientModule, but only the old HttpModule. Try to remove the HttpModule from the imports array and instead use the HttpClientModule. It may be that you're telling the ngx-loading to use the new HttpClient service but it doesn't know how to handle it because the module was not imported. I'm not really sure though, but mixing both modules and services is probably not a good idea

Comment: Hi, I removed the HttpModule and i tried only with the HttpClientModule but don't works yet. I really do not know what's going on.

Comment: Do you also get an error if you simply import the TranslateModule without the `forRoot` part?